# Golang: Bigquery Check Unique Key before Inserting

Tags: go, unique, google-bigquery

I am implementing the insertion to google bigquery using golang.
The file has duplicates, and needs to be update everyday. However, the duplicates should not be inserted into the bigquery.
I use some apis by google cloud platform and golang. However, I have not found any apis can either check if unique before inserting or setting to unique for specific fields in schema.
I am using a wrapper api and calling the function directly. However, the function does not check if the field is unique. Please suggest any bigquery apis for golang has unique key checking or unique key setting to the schema. Much appreciate! I will update replies immediately.

Comment: Use tabledata's list method with a filter to check if the entries exist already. Basically, do a select, if you get something back then don't insert the corresponding record, if you don't then it's new and you can safely insert.

Comment: Cant really do that. It creates an expense.

Comment: Without the field having a primary key constraint to prevent the insert, there is no way you can ensure uniqueness without increasing the cost of insert. There's no way around checking whether or not the record exists.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I think I have to choose not to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery, there is no any API or Function to specifically do uniqueness check of given field
You can meet your requirements by constructing your insert as join of source with destination and insert only unique ones
This might require you first to insert your data into “temp” table and then do above join in GBQ

Comment: Thank you for answering me. Do you mean that I need to create a new table and copy rows from one to the other? That will cause some querying expenses

Comment: I think, uniqueness check will incur extra querying expenses no matter what final option you will use

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I don't think I should do uniqueness anymore then.

Answer (score 0):

Check the doc for [StructSaver](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#StructSaver) struct.

It has a field `InserdID`, exactly for what you're asking:

```
// If non-empty, BigQuery will use InsertID to de-duplicate insertions
// of this row on a best-effort basis.
InsertID string
```

Comment: However do note that the InsertID is potentially short-lived (the documentation guarantees at least one minute). So there is a fair chance that inserting with the same InsertID some time after that, won't actually be deduplicated (@see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery)